# fread() under mingw not working properly

Tags: c, fread, mingw-w64, msys

I have written a C application under Linux with GTK. A friend wanted to test it under Windows. So we compiled it using MinGW64.

The GUI and everything looks/works as it should. However, the fread() call does not work.

```
read = fread(workbuff, sizeof(char), rec_data_length, bin_file);

    if (read != rec_data_length) {
        /* Here is some error handling */
    }
```

rec_data_length is 608. I ensured that the file is not corrupted and that these 608 bytes are available. The function returns 87.

Can someone explain this to me? Why does it work under Linux but not under Windows?

Comment: Is that the first, last and only call you have to read from the file? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: No I used "r". It is not the only call to fread. There are some other calls. The problem is. The file is multiple giga bytes big. with a small file it works well.

Comment: Yes. Thank you all. Changing fopen's "r" to "rb" solved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with reading from this file was, that I opened a binary file with

```
fopen("foo", "r");
```

This worked fine under Linux. But on Windows I had to change it to

```
fopen("foo", "rb");
```

This solution works on both systems and behaves now as expected.